# Apollo client devtool couldn't detect Apollo Client in react native app

Tags: react-native, graphql, google-chrome-devtools, apollo-client, graphql-js

Apollo client dev tool can't connect to my app. I have passed connectToDevTools as true in ApolloClient constructor but nothing happens. I have also tried [this package](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) but apollo tab shows blank page.

Comment: do you had more than one endpoint in your `clientConfigs` registered?

Answer (score 1):

after restarting and cleaning cache its working fine from my side.